# Program/debug via the built-in USB in EFM32

Tags: microcontroller, usb, programming

How to program/debug the Silabs EFM32 via the USB built-in interface? Is it possible to do that with a simple USB cable, without any adapter?

Comment: if you have only EFM32, which i see as silabs MCU, you need a adapter. adapter is called programmer. do you have experience in programming MCUs, boot loaders etc? else, better to buy a dev. kit of EFM32 and get good hands on.

Comment: the adapter or the dev kit use the SWD interface for programming and debuging, my question is about the built-in USB. i have some experience with AVRs, but think that this is insuffisant to deal with EFM32 devices  wich are ARM cortex based.

Comment: you have to use the programmer at least once. later, you can have your bootloader USB set up ready. then, you will be able to program using built in USB. All ARM cortex M supports SWD but you nee to have a programmer still. https://www.arm.com/products/system-ip/coresight-debug-trace simple one i use is keil ULINK2

Comment: EFM32 with built-in USB have already bootloader, so i can program using the USB, but how about debugging???

Comment: If there is no IDE, then I would use UART to dump some debug data but it will be definitely slow. Let me wait to see responses from others who have worked on EFM32

Answer (score 1):

> how program/debug silabs EFM32 via the USB built-in interface

Program: Yes, you can do that over USB with a bootloader. See [AN0042](https://www.silabs.com/Support%20Documents/TechnicalDocs/AN0042.pdf).

Debug: No, for debugging you would need an SWD debugger, like the one on the DK or STK. I recommend using one of the STKs as there is plenty example code available for these and they have the debugger included.

Comment: So USB has only access to the flash??? please give further details...

Comment: First RTFM. This is answered in AN0042 - it contains all available commands in chapter `1.3`.

Comment: ....in p0 of AN0042: `The bootloader enables users to program the EFM32 or EZR32 through an UART or
an USB **CDC** class virtual UART without the need for a **debugger**.`... i don't see why debug is not doable?? there is no explication of this in the AN!!.

Comment: The bootloader has no control over the MCU once your app is  started. Hence no debug over the bootloader - you would have to implement some debug stuff yourself in your app. Both complicated and error-prone.

Comment: I am sorry but my question concern the USB not the bootloader!!!...